# Выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу | С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11

```
char *username() {
    char userch[10];
    DWORD size;
    size = sizeof(userch);
    GetUserName(userch, &size);
    return userch;
}
int main() {
    CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\" + username() +"\\AppData\\123", NULL); // выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или перечисления без области видимости
}
```

Заранее, спасибо за помощь))

Comment: неочень понятен вопрос

Comment: Ну, компилятор выдает ошибку, которая описывается в комментарии. Не знаю как решить, прошу помощи

Comment: Кроме указанной проблемы с конкатенцией строк, ф-ия username возвращает адрес локальной строки.

Answer (score 3):

В языках С и С++ нет такой функциональности, как конкатенация С-строк и строковых литералов через `+`. Так что ни о каком

```
"C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\AppData\\123"
```

не может быть и речи. С точки зрения языка, вы выполняете адресную арифметику, в которой должен участвовать указатель (ваш массив `"C:\\Users\\"`) и целое число. Так как ваше `username()` - это не целое число, вы получаете сообщение об ошибке.

Соединить С-строки, можно только средствами библиотеки. Средствами стандартной библиотеки С это можно сделать так

```
char directory[1024];
snprintf(directory, sizeof directory, "%s%s%s", 
  "C:\\Users\\", username(), "\\AppData\\123");
// Убедиться, что возвращенное значение < sizeof directory

CreateDirectory(directory, NULL);
```

В С++ у вас есть `std::string`, который вам в этом поможет

```
std::string directory = 
  std::string("C:\\Users\\") + username() + "\\AppData\\123";

CreateDirectory(directory.c_str(), NULL);
```

А начиная с С++14 то же можно записать несколько короче

```
using namespace std::string_literals;    
std::string directory = "C:\\Users\\"s + username() + "\\AppData\\123";

CreateDirectory(directory.c_str(), NULL);
```

и уже почти как в вашем оригинальном варианте

```
using namespace std::string_literals;    
CreateDirectory(("C:\\Users\\"s + username() + "\\AppData\\123").c_str(), NULL);
```

---

Вообще-то надо заметить, что в Windows директория `Users` совсем не обязана располагаться на `C:`. И конструировать вручную пути типа

```
"C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\AppData\\123"
```

является порочной практикой. В Windows у вас есть переменные окружения `APPDATA`, `LOCALAPPDATA`, `USERPROFILE` и т.п. которые и содержат правильные пути.

Comment: Благодарю, забыл про это

Comment: ну да, а то вопрос мог быть другим - например можно ли так сделать?...